# How do you connect remotely using Python + Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to figure out how to connect to my remote webdriver instance.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
from selenium.remote.webdriver import WebDriver

driver = WebDriver("http://172.16.205.129:4444", "firefox", "ANY")
driver.get('http://google.com')
driver.quit()
```

I find that I can't connect and will get a connection refused, or if i play around with the code, occasionally a time out.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is out of date, look at selenium.webdriver.Remote() in Selenium 2.0b3.

Answer (score 4):

You need to ensure `selenium` server hub and node are set up before the test. Please [refer to this](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2).

Example on hub run

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar -role hub
```

Example on node to connect to hub ,run

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.5.0.jar -role webdriver -hub
   http://localhost:4444/grid/register -port 5555
```

You can have as many nodes as you want.

Comment: How could localhost work for the hub, if the hub and node aren't the same. Shouldn't that be 10.0.2.2 instead?

Answer (score 2):

change the following line from

```
driver = WebDriver("http://172.16.205.129:4444", "firefox", "ANY")
```

to

```
driver = WebDriver("http://172.16.205.129:4444/wd/hub", "firefox", "ANY")
```

Notice "/wd/hub" is appended to the url in the first argument.