# How do I translate this to Python?

Tags: python, ruby, selenium

```
s1 = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote.new :url => "http://localhost:4444/wb/pub"
```

This is Ruby. What's the equivalent in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This S/O answer should demonstrate the Syntax you need:

[How do you connect remotely using Python + Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850460/how-do-you-connect-remotely-using-python-webdriver)